# set messagettl of a message in Azure Queue using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, azure-queues

I'm trying to post a message to azure queue service using python3 by making a POST request and specifying `messagettl` to `-1`  which indicates the message does not expire. In the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message I have to specify the `Authorization` key and `Date` which indicates the time at which the response was initiated (both parameters are required), and the body must be an XML, here what I did:

```py
url = "https://MyStorageAccountName.queue.core.windows.net/MyQueueName?messagettl=-1"
xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<QueueMessage>  
<MessageText>First message</MessageText>  
</QueueMessage> """

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
'Authorization' : 'SharedKey MyStorageAccountName:MyKey1....==',
'Date' : str(datetime.utcnow())}

print(requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers).text)
```

And the response is an error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
   <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:44d1fd4c-c003-001d-215...000
Time:2020-11-20T15:39:10.9730253Z</Message>
   <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The Date header in the request is incorrect.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

which piece of the puzzle I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

In headers I fixed the issue by replacing `str(datetime.utcnow())` with `format_date_time(mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()))` and fixed the related date error, but I have a new error and don't know how to sign my key:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
   <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:359305a5-a003-0034...
Time:2020-11-20T15:59:12.4611176Z</Message>
   <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'HACSNj/4PwH...MyKey...YJQ==' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'POST

application/xml
Fri, 20 Nov 2020 15:59:09 GMT
/MystorageAccount/MyQueueName'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using python SDK to do this is much easier, just try the code below:

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient

connectionString = "<storage account connection string>"
queueName = "<queue name>"

queueClient = QueueClient.from_connection_string(connectionString, queueName)

queueClient.send_message(content = 'hello sdk', time_to_live=-1)
```

Result:

[image]

For info about python queue client sdk, just refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueclient?view=azure-python).

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see it in the doc but thank you @Stanley you saved me !